# Recording a search function with Selenium IDE

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium, selenium-ide

I want to record and test the search function on my website.
When I test it manually and tip something in it works. For example: I want to search the word "title". I start typing "t", then "i", then "t", then "l" and "e". After typing "t" a few results are displayed => perfect. 
When I record this test with Selenium IDE it doesn't work because there is no search button to click. It is an automatic searching bar which already starts searching while typing in.
The command is "type", value is "title". When the test is done nothing happens, so the website doesn't search because I can not make a command with "click and wait", ID = search button, because there is no search button!

Comment: What html driver are you using? Did you try with FirefoxDriver?

Comment: Paste the html code from the selenium IDE so that we can debug the problem. The basic problem is with Selenium IDE is not waiting for the auto suggestion to populate. you need to decrease the speed of the execution.Also you need to specify proper locators for the autosuggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to perform searching. this code is work for me. check and let me know

```
open  | https://www.google.co.in/  |
type  | id=gbqfq                   | selenium
pause | 1000
click | //*[@id="gbqfbw"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using selenium IDE 2.4.0
and Firefox version 24.0

use the below code for auto search:

```
command: type , Type: //*[@id='searchbox'] , value: flower

command: typeKeysAndWait , Type: //*[@id='searchbox'], value:flower
```

Use both commands  in Selenium IDE the search will work

or you can Use :

```
command: type , Type: //*[@id='searchbox'] , value: flower

command: typeKeys , Type: //*[@id='searchbox'], value:flower
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried automating same flow with Google's auto-complete. The problem, prima-facie appears to be the speed of test execution. Try to reduce the speed of test using the slider shown in the image. Make it slow.

**OR**

you may insert some wait before he action you perform after the search.

[image]